# Windows Phone and ANSI C (not C++) library

Tags: c, windows-phone

Is there any way to write / include ANSI C written library to my Windows Phne 8 app project? I know it's possible with Windows Phone Runtime Component for C++ but here is my question, it is possible for ANSI C? The goal is cross-mobile library for Android, iOS and windows Phone

Comment: C++ can use C libraries, so it might be possible for you to make a C++ wrapper around the library.

Comment: So here is no possibility to run it completely native? Will I be forced to use some wrappers or workarounds?

Comment: Using C is probably not the best solution for cross-platform development; you'd have to build non-OO wrappers around different OO APIs for starters - which is a project in itself quite apart from your application, and probably a backward step.  Consider something like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), or [Monocross](http://monocross.net/) which use C#.  That is likely to be the path of least resistance.

Comment: Thank you guys, I made wrapper and it still works :) so probably it's a good way to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has [fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777333/add-dllimport-support-for-net-in-windows-phone-8) the `[DllImport]` in WP 8.1. If you target WP 8.1, you can compile your ANSI C library into the DLL and invoke your DLL directly from the C# code, without any C++/CX component.

**Update:** Please note you must use visual studio to build that DLL. Also, remember the native code is always CPU-specific, which means you’ll need separate x86 build for the emulator, and ARM build for testing on hardware devices, and for the store.